# Custom error page in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, error-handling

I'm trying to create custom error page in my web-application instead of white-label pages. As I know all I need to do in Spring Boot is to add an error.html file under resources/static/templates path, so I did it (I'm using Thymeleaf). But now instead of white-label pages, it shows me tomcat error pages. I have also tried to add:

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=true
```

to the properties file, but the result is the same - container error pages. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add these lines to the web.xml configuration file that redirects all the Tomcat 404 errors to the defined page `error.html`:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```